# why my angular js code does not work

Tags: angularjs, debugging

This code is used to fetch the data from my web api, but it does not work. Ｉ　have checked again and again, but noting happened. please help me, whether I hand a wrong code?

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
    MyApp.factory('Service', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var urlBase = 'http://localhost:1883/api';
        var datafactory = {};
        Service.getCustomers = function () {
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/Customers1');
        };
        return datafactory;
    }]);

    MyApp.Controller('UpdateController', ['$scope', 'datafactory', function ($scope, datafactory) {
        getCustomers();

        function getCustomers() {
            datafactory.getCustomers()
            .then(function (data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
            });
        }
    }]);
```

here is the error from browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0XVv.png)

Comment: With question like _"Why isn't this code working?"_/_"why am I getting this error"_ it is difficult for volunteer on SO to help you. You should _include the desired behavior_, a _specific problem or error_ and the _shortest code_ necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: What is `Service`? Where is it defined? Haven't you noticed the error in your browser console?

Comment: Thank you very much, I  have added my error, I think my code is very simple, why not fetch the data from webapi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, you return an empty object. Change `Service.getCustomers` to `datafactory.getCustomers`.